# Scipy quadratic 1D Interpolation over a big list of 1D sequences is very slow

Tags: python, performance, scipy, interpolation

I have a big list (500 000+) of 1D sequences and I want to quadratically interpolate each one of them. 
As they don't have the same size, I am forced to loop over them and apply scipy.interpolate.interp1D over each sequence. It is very slow and I am looking for a way to fasten things up.

For the moment, I have the following function:

def interp_sequences(sequences, max_len):

```
'''Interpolate sequences in order to reduce their length to max_len

    sequences (list of numpy arrays): The sequences to interpolate

    maxlen (int): The maximum length of the sequence: All sequences will be interpolated to match this length
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    returns (ndarray): The interpolated sequences
'''

interp_obs = np.zeros((len(obs_list), 5, 120))
# Looping is dirty... But the sequences have different lengths...
for idx, s in enumerate(sequences): 
    original_len = s.shape[1]
    f = interp1d(np.arange(original_len), s, 'quadratic', axis = 1)
    interp_seq = np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, np.linspace(0, original_len -1, num = max_len))
    interp_obs[idx] = interp_seq

return interp_obs
```

I have also tried with a list comprehension which does not improve the performance.
I would like to use numba-scipy but it does not support interpolation for the moment.
Thank you in advance !

Comment: I'm not sure but I imagine your primary problem is `apply_along_axis`, which is slow. You can run `f(np.linspace(0, original_len -1, num = max_len))` directly, which should be much faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply! Indeed, It cuts the running time by 15%. However, it is still too long for my workcase....